# Running a T4 template using C#

Tags: c#, t4, customtool

I have T4 template (mycode.tt) which generates a cs file. I usually right click the tt file and select RunCustomTool which internally takes an xml file and generate code for me. Now i want to run the custom tool using a c# windows application. So onclick of a button i want to run the Custom Tool . Is it possible to run the CustomTool from c#.

Edit:

I have 2 tt files and one of them doesn't have a codebehind cs file.  But another has a .cs file attached with it and i am invoking the second file's TransformText() method from the first .tt file. So i need to invoke the first file.So i cannot use the TransformText() method. Is there a way to dynamically call the textTemplate file ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend the preprocessed route as answered above by @jb_.

As an alternative, if you need your templates to still be editable without a compile step for use with your custom C# application, and the application will only be deployed on machines alongside Visual Studio, you can write a custom host.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126519.aspx

Answer (score 18):

You can easily achieve it, when you using VS2010. If you add a new file to the project, choose a preprocessed text template file. You can edit the template just as normal. Instead of generating the output directly, the file generates the code that is generated normally. I know it sounds confusing. But what you see in your output file is the code generated by the text templating toolkit to get your output (more or less).

This is a short example of a preprocessed text template named "TestTemplate.tt" and how do you use it in your code:

The tt-file:

> ```
> <#@ template language="C#" #>
> Some output.
> ```

Code:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Diagnostics;
>
> namespace Test
> {
>     class Program
>     {
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             TestTemplate testTemplate = new TestTemplate();
>             Debug.Print(testTemplate.TransformText());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: For an existing template you could change the Custom Tool in the properties from `TextTemplatingFileGenerator` to `TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor`.

Comment: How do you provide parameters?